# Jquery Mobile : listview remote autocomplete official demo not working

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm implementing a remote autocomplete on a listview (Jquery Mobile 1.4.5) based on the official example : https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview-autocomplete-remote/ . The official demo is actually not working : if you try it, nothing is displayed when you type a few characters.

As I'm debugging it with my own code, I can see I successfully retrieve remote data and populate the listview (ul) with the expected results (li). The problem seems to be on the 2 last lines of the JS code :

```
$ul.listview( "refresh" );
$ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
```

The items (li) are just not displayed in the listview.
No error in the console. But if I display in the console the HTML content of the listview (ul), I see that all li elements have the class "ui-screen-hidden"...

Any idea of what's happening ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The example is ok, You need to follow the instructions of the API provider here: https://geobytes.com/free-ajax-cities-jsonp-api/ (maybe it is time to switch to https)

Comment: Hello deblocker, actually the API is not my issue here. My debugging shows I manage to get remote data, add the li elements in the listview, but they are just not displayed. As if the listview refresh had no effet (but I have no error in the console).

Comment: Hard to guess without more info, because the official demo is working just fine (I tested it with the updated https endpoint from AutocompleteCity). There must be something else. Maybe You can post the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When You type "*cnn*" inside Your `input`, You will get the response records. BUT: inside the response from that "*cnn*" query, there isn't any record which contains the substring "*cnn*", so all `listitems` are filtered out and will be hidden by the framework.

From the [documentation](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/filterable/):

> By default, the text contained in each child is used for filtering

Now, maybe You need to rethink the workflow/usabilty of Your application. Do You really need a filterable?

- Maybe You just only need to post the
  query and display a nicely formatted list?
- Do You need to filter again the received (already filtered) data-set?

A possible solution could be a custom [filter function](https://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#option-filterCallback), or maybe You can set the `data-filtertext` attribute of the `<li>` to something like `"cnn " + item.code`, to avoid the initial filtering.

As You haven't provided inside Your question any information about Your desired workflow, the answer is now up to You.

Comment: Wow brilliant, thank you very much deblocker. I only need to post the query and display a nicely formatted list, so I know what to do next.